# sparse gradient in text classification with pytorch

Tags: optimization, pytorch, nlp, text-classification, torchtext

I am trying to train a text classification module.

When I use `Adam`, `RAdam`, or `RMSProp` for my optimizer, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Adam/RAdam/RMSProp does not support sparse gradients
```

So I tried using `SparseAdam` and I got this error:

```
RuntimeError: SparseAdam does not support dense gradients, please consider Adam instead
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please share a bit of your code and network architecture